# Kendo Chart not performing as expected

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-chart

My understanding of Kendo bar charts in series is that the data value should sum up per item, but in this screen shot each set of bars is an interval, and based on interval 1 input data I should have 3 colors(services)summing to a total of 22, instead I just have the largest service displaying it's portion of the bar, what am I missing here?

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-saha-hg8oq3

[Imgur link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ssO0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Self solved, was grouping on wrong variable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).